# Like ISNULL % doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SP with a simple query:

```
@first_name nvarchar(50) = null
AS
BEGIN
Select * from empTable where first_name like %ISNULL(@first_name, first_name)%
END
```

What I want to do is, if the user enter a value to @first_name, the query should act like `Select * from empTable where first_name like '%John%'`

And if the use doesn't enter name, I should be able to return everything - as if there is no where condition.

It keeps telling me there is a syntax error in my SP

Comment: You can't put a wildcard on IS NULL.  You should just use a different statement if your @first_name is still blank at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
@first_name nvarchar(50) = null
AS
BEGIN
Select * from empTable where first_name like '%' + ISNULL(@first_name, first_name) + '%'
END
```